# Centre Woocommerce shortcode products

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to center a Woocommerce shortcode product object, see product example 'Chanel printed logo shopper', here: http://vintageheirloom.biz/blog/2013/10/forever-fashion-everlasting-trends/

Woocommerce provide this code: [product id="6606"].

I've tried using standard Wordpress align center, I've tried putting inside a div along the lines of:

```
div.displayed {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

No luck, any ideas?

Much appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below code to your CSS, As you have only one item in it. Not suggested if you have multiple `li`

**CSS**

```
.displayed ul.products li.product {
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue and made like that:

In Wordpress:

```
<div class="single_product">[products ids="185" columns="1"]</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.single_product {
float: none;
margin: 0 35%;
}
```